# Translate "Table","Figure", etc. in tufte-latex

Tags: languages, tufte

Recently I discovered the fantastic package `tufte-latex`. I have to write an assignment for college, and I thought that it would be a good idea to use the `handout` class include in this package.

It works great, but I have a little problem: I don't live in an English-speaking country, but when I insert the date with `\today` or a table, a figure, etc. with a caption, the output is something like "Table 1: ...", that is, in English.

If I use other standard document class such as `article`, the output is in my language.

I *think* that I have to modify the file `tufte-common.def`, but I am not sure, and I don't want to screw it up.

Any advice on how to be able to translate this package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tufte-latex` can be 'switched' to another language the usual way. Put

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

in the header of your document and the language is switched, in this case to german. For spanish you could use `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. I am not sure which parts won't work for you. If you provide a MWE, I could look further into that.

Comment: You are completely right. I made a typo calling the language package and, as it was the first time I was using `tufte-latex`, my first thought was that it had some problem handling other languages. Thank you.